# Bootstrap multiselect form no validation message when no option selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have a form on my page that uses multiselect. Here is the relevant part of the form

```
<select required id="reqs2" name="reqs2[]" multiple="multiple" class="form-control">
<option value="option1">Option1</option>
<option value="option2">Option2</option>
<option value="option3">Option3</option>
</select>
```

and at the bottom of the page I have

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#reqs2').multiselect();
});
</script>
```

It all works fine if the user makes at least one selection, but if they don't make a selection, the form doesn't submit and no validation error message is displayed. Validation messages show for other required input fields, but not this one.

Any ideas what changes I need to make?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This may help--> [GitHub Issues](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/issues/347)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, but I managed to solve it by removing the "required" element from the field on the form and adding a line to my php file as follows

Instead of

```
$try2 =  implode(', ', $_POST['reqs']);
```

I add this before so it now becomes

```
if(isset($_POST['reqs'])) 
$try2 =  implode(', ', $_POST['reqs']);
```

Now client can skip the field without an error showing
This seems to check if there is an entry in the field - if there is it implodes it; if not, it ignores it.